# How to use FFMPEG with java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to convert sequence of images to a video.

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i sample%d.png -s 320x240 -aspect 4:3 output.flv
```

This works fine for me!

Now i'm trying to use the above command to run through java code.

How can i run the ffmpeg command using `Runtime.getRuntime()` from my java code.

Please share your thoughts..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -r 1 -i sample%d.png -s 320x240 -aspect 4:3 output.flv");
```