# Android, How to convert video into slow motion and play it in slow motion using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, motion

In Android, How to convert video into slow motion and play it in slow motion using FFmpeg.

I am using FFmpeg command :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" output.mkv

Link : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video
```

but i can't pass "setpts=2.0*PTS" command with Double Quote in String

```
    String cmd1 = "-i " + inputpath.mp4 + " " + "-filter:v" + " " 
+ "setpts=0.5*PTS"  
+ " " +
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/hij.mp4";
```

if you have any better solution for converting video into slow motion or fast motion then it will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If there's no whitespace in your filterchain then there's no need for enclosing quotes, so `-filter:v setpts=2*PTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

String cmd1 = "-i " + inputpath.mp4 + " " + "-filter:v" + " " + "\"setpts=0.5*PTS\"" + " " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/hij.mp4";

Just escape the double quotes with backslashes.

Comment: i done like this but getting no result.
Progress Dialog is running like this.

Processing 
handler_name  : IsoMedia
File Produce by Google
5-11-2011

Comment: [How to use FFMPEG with java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612871/how-to-use-ffmpeg-with-java)
Did you look this answer? I hope it can help you.